# Table value function to pass as parameter to generate output inside case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

My dataset looks like below

SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @ELECTRONICS TABLE
(
    RESISTORID INT, 
    CAPACITORID VARCHAR(10),    
    VOLT  DECIMAL(6,2), 
    WATT  INT,  
    PASSIVENUMBER INT    
) 

INSERT @ELECTRONICS
SELECT 100, 'TH',   1.2,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'TH',   1.2,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 'TH',   1.5,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'TH',   -2.9,   5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 500, 'RT',   3.3,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 540, 'TH',   0,      5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 540, 'SN',   3.3,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 540, 'UL',   4.2,    5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 800, 'TH',   -2.4,   5,  93 UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 'RN',   2.2,    4,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 'RN',   2.5,    6,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'RN',   1.2,    9,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'RN',   1.2,    9,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 'RN',   1.5,    9,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'RN',   -2.9,   9,  35 UNION ALL
SELECT 800, 'RN',   -2.4,   9,  31
```

I am trying to write a Table Valued UDF which accepts a parameter, `@PASSIVENUMBER`, and generates value for `POWERTHRESHOLD` and `RESISTORID` based on the `CAPACITORID`, `VOLT` and `WATT`.

Function to be used in below SQL code.

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN RESISTORID IN ('100','540') THEN 'A03' ELSE 'A01' END AS RESISTORID,
    CASE WHEN CAPACITORID = 'TH' AND VOLT >0 THEN (VOLT * 1000) 
    WHEN CAPACITORID = 'TH' AND VOLT = 0 THEN (WATT * 1000)
    WHEN CAPACITORID <> 'TH' AND VOLT >0 THEN VOLT
    ELSE WATT END AS POWERTHRESHOLD
FROM @ELECTRONICS
WHERE PASSIVENUMBER = 93

SELECT * ,CASE WHEN RESISTORID IN ('300','800') THEN 'B03' ELSE 'B01' END AS RESISTORID,
    CASE WHEN CAPACITORID = 'RN' AND VOLT >0 THEN (VOLT * 10*3/56) 
    WHEN CAPACITORID = 'RN' AND VOLT = 0 THEN (WATT * 100*2/21)
    WHEN CAPACITORID <> 'RN' AND VOLT >10 THEN VOLT
    ELSE WATT END AS POWERTHRESHOLD
FROM @ELECTRONICS
WHERE PASSIVENUMBER = 35
```

Output when PASSIVENUMBER = 93

```
RESISTORID  CAPACITORID VOLT    WATT    PASSIVENUMBER   RESISTORID  POWERTHRESHOLD
100 TH  1.20    5   93  A03 1200.00
200 TH  1.20    5   93  A01 1200.00
300 TH  1.50    5   93  A01 1500.00
100 TH  -2.90   5   93  A03 5.00
500 RT  3.30    5   93  A01 3.30
540 TH  0.00    5   93  A03 5000.00
540 SN  3.30    5   93  A03 3.30
540 UL  4.20    5   93  A03 4.20
800 TH  -2.40   5   93  A01 5.00
```

Output when PASSIVENUMBER = 35

```
RESISTORID  CAPACITORID VOLT    WATT    PASSIVENUMBER   RESISTORID  POWERTHRESHOLD
300 RN  2.20    4   35  B03 2200.00
300 RN  2.50    6   35  B03 2500.00
100 RN  1.20    9   35  B01 1200.00
200 RN  1.20    9   35  B01 1200.00
300 RN  1.50    9   35  B03 1500.00
100 RN  -2.90   9   35  B01 9.00
```

How to implement a function that checks a value with a case statement.

Code I tried something like this is not giving proper result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnchkID]
(
    @PASSIVENUMBER INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE 
            WHEN CAPACITORID = RN and @VOLT>0 THEN VOLT * 1000
            
            ELSE WATT from @ELECTRONICS
        END 
END
```

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does your code work? Where are you stuck? You have I assume consulted the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). FYI its a `case` *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @Fabio: How to implement function which check value with case statement.

Comment: Pass all "external" values to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a function is well [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488932/table-value-function-to-pass-as-parameter-to-generate-output-inside-case-stateme) so should be your starting point as they have plenty of examples to get you started.

I recommend an *Inline Table-Valued Function* as they typically perform significantly better than a *Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function*.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnchkID]
(
    @PASSIVENUMBER INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
    SELECT RESISTORID, CAPACITORID, VOLT, WATT, PASSIVENUMBER
        , CASE WHEN RESISTORID IN ('100','540') THEN 'A03' ELSE 'A01' END AS NEWRESISTORID
        , CASE WHEN PASSIVENUMBER = 93 THEN
            CASE WHEN CAPACITORID = 'TH' AND VOLT > 0 THEN (VOLT * 1000) 
            WHEN CAPACITORID = 'TH' AND VOLT = 0 THEN (WATT * 1000)
            WHEN CAPACITORID <> 'TH' AND VOLT > 0 THEN VOLT
            ELSE WATT END
        WHEN PASSIVENUMBER = 35 THEN
            CASE WHEN CAPACITORID = 'RN' AND VOLT >0 THEN (VOLT * 10*3/56) 
            WHEN CAPACITORID = 'RN' AND VOLT = 0 THEN (WATT * 100*2/21)
            WHEN CAPACITORID <> 'RN' AND VOLT >10 THEN VOLT
            ELSE WATT END
        END AS POWERTHRESHOLD
    FROM @ELECTRONICS
    WHERE PASSIVENUMBER = @PASSIVENUMBER;
```

Note: Your calculated column cannot have the same name as your existing column, hence `NEWRESISTORID` instead of `RESISTORID`.

Comment: Yes! I agree with you

Comment: @Dale K: How to handle for CAPACITORID = 'RN', Please suggest. The second select

Comment: @DaleK: Thanks a lot Dale, but how can we handle if two select statement have different logic. as i have edited the question. i have total 5 passive number with different logic. kindly share your suggestion.

Comment: @MitaliNath I've edited my answer... but in future ask a new question. You can't keep changing your question once you have answers.

Comment: @DaleK: Thanks a ton Dale..... very happy to learn something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Start from here... and change the code accordingly

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnchkID] (@PASSIVENUMBER INT)
RETURNS @fnchkID TABLE
(
RESISTORID INT, 
CAPACITORID VARCHAR(10),    
VOLT  DECIMAL(6,2), 
WATT  INT,  
PASSIVENUMBER INT
)AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @fnchkID
    select * from YourTable WHERE PASSIVENUMBER=@PASSIVENUMBER /* Your Logic goes here*/
    RETURN
END
```

Call the TVF

```
select * from [dbo].[fnchkID] (93)
```